# Extract .tar File to Current Directory Automatically with Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, loops, extract, tar

I'm totally new to the world of bash, and I'm currently working on a script that will loop through a large directory and extract any .tar files it finds into it's current location.

I'm using the following script:

```
for a in in /home/davidwright/attachments/*/*.tar
do
  echo "extracting $x"
  tar -xvf $x
done
```

Currently the file is extracting fine, but it is extracting to the location of my script. I need it to extract within the .tar's current directory.

The solution is probably very simple, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
-C, --directory DIR
              change to directory DIR
```

and `$(dirname "$x")` for file directory

```
for x in in /home/davidwright/attachments/*/*.tar
do
  echo "extracting $x"
  tar -xvf "$x" -C "$(dirname "$x")"
done
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Didn't think to use dirname. 
Thanks!